Timer autoconnect not working on Vision Pro, works in simulator
The following solution works perfectly in the Vision Pro simulator but does not work on the device.
Im creating a count down view that should count down from 3 and then reset to its initial value and also call a completion handler. I have extracted out the code for starting a timer and running some code every second.
Start a timer:
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

Do something every sec:
Text("\(secondsRemaining)")
        .font(.extraLargeTitle)
        .contentTransition(.numericText())
        .onReceive(timer)  { _ in
            // called in simulator, but not on device. 
        }
    

Anyone have any idea why stating a timer this way isn't working when running it on a Vision Pro?
UPDATE

Here is the entire code:
struct CountDownView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State private var isActive = true

    let duration: Int

    @State private var secondsRemaining: Int
    @Binding var isCountingDown: Bool

    var onEnded: (() -> Void)?

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    init(duration: Int, onEnded: (() -> Void)?, start: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.onEnded = onEnded
        self.duration = duration
        self._isCountingDown = start
        self._secondsRemaining = State(initialValue: duration)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(secondsRemaining, format: .number)
            .font(.extraLargeTitle)
            .contentTransition(.numericText())
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) {
                if scenePhase == .active {
                    isActive = true
                } else {
                    isActive = false
                }
            }
            .onReceive(timer)  { _ in
                if isCountingDown {
                    if secondsRemaining > 0 {
                        withAnimation {
                            secondsRemaining -= 1
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.onTerminated()
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    func onTerminated() {
           timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
           self.secondsRemaining = duration
           onEnded?()
      }
}


If you can use TimelineView

Maybe, but I am implementing a count down to 0. And when secondsRemaining == 0 then I want to call a function. Haven't found a way of doing this with the TimelineView @loremipsum
